# What are all of Wordpress' public/direct entry-points?

Tags: wordpress, redirect, symlink

I realize this is a bit of a strange question, but to put a long story short, we have a few Wordpress installs whose files are loaded through a symbolic link (the symlink is in the document root whereas Wordpress is not).

For this to work, I need to have a list of all Wordpress files that are usually loaded directly from the web browser (either by the user or through AJAX), such as: `index.php`, `wp-login.php`, *(all theme files*)* ...

An example of files that are *not* loaded directly: `wp-load.php`, `wp-config.php`, `wp-blog-header.php`...

[*] Theme files are an exception; they actually exist in the document root.

**Edit:** You might wonder, what is the point of this? It is so that we can cut down on the extra files on the server; it's useless to have thousands of identical files from each Wordpress website. The `wp-content` directory has been left there since it's what changes between websites. Am I aware of the consequences of such a set up? I believe I am.

**Edit 2:**

http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Files

Answer (score 2):

Here is a list of entry points based on `require( 'wp-load.php' );`

https://github.com/szepeviktor/WPHW/blob/master/wp-entry-points.md

And a Trac ticket about their deficiencies
https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/28364

Answer (score 1):

So far, the following fixes my issue:

```
ln -s /var/www/vhosts/mainsite/httpdocs/index.php /var/www/vhosts/subsite/httpdocs/index.php
ln -s /var/www/vhosts/mainsite/httpdocs/wp-login.php /var/www/vhosts/subsite/httpdocs/wp-login.php
ln -s /var/www/vhosts/mainsite/httpdocs/wp-admin /var/www/vhosts/subsite/httpdocs/wp-admin
ln -s /var/www/vhosts/mainsite/httpdocs/wp-includes /var/www/vhosts/subsite/httpdocs/wp-includes
```